# Checking if LINQ to XMLXPathReader loads the whole document and why XPathReader cannot be found in VB.NET

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a question - how come there is XPathReader in C# but not in VB.NET? Or is it that I simply haven't done enough research to find it out? Because I've been looking it up quite a bit and I came up with two questions

1. LINQ to XML. I was wondering if this loads the entire document. Because I think it does. I want to avoid this. I don't want to read the whole document in memory.
2. XPathReader - Why can't I find it for VB.NET?

Comment: What do you mean, "you can't find it for VB.NET?" What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: I added XPathReader in my VB.NET project. It wasn't giving any import suggestions - so I imported the stuff manually that was imported in the C# example. Still nothing. I then googled it and saw no examples for XPathReader for VB.NET, only for C#.

Comment: Again, what do you mean "still nothing"? Was there a compilation error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465237/what-ever-happened-to-xpathreader

Comment: I did read that but obviously I misunderstood it completely. Thank you. However, can anyone answer my first question? Does LINQ to XML load the whole document? And would XPathReader be faster?

Comment: XPathReader is not part of .NET. Are you thinking of [XPathDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx)?

Comment: XPathReader is something someone from Microsoft made, I guess. But I was wondering if LINQ to XML is faster than XPathReader. I am looking for the fastest way to grab elements from a large XML file basically

Comment: The fastest way is to try it and find out. XML processing may not even be the slow part of the application.

Comment: Well what I am doing is that I am inserting rows into a datatable and I am getting values of an xml node through it's parent node. Which I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727951/vb-net-for-loop-too-slow-when-grabbing-xml. Anyway, it seems that doing it for 600 nodes becomes pretty slow and takes 2 seconds.